# DateTimeFormat.forPattern won't use text for month

Tags: java, jodatime, datetime-format

It's documented [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) that using the string "MMM" for the month, a text is used and not a number:

> Month: 3 or over, use text, otherwise use number.

I'm doing `DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MMM/yyyy" ).print( DateTime.now() )` and instead of returning `05/Apr/2016`, it's returning `05/4/2016`.

How can I make it return the month in a text format?

Java 6

Comment: should try dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Can't reproduce. I just tested with my locale and I have `05/avr./2016`. Code: `System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MMM/yyyy" ).print( DateTime.now() ));`

Comment: @manikantgautam No... `MM` returns a number (e.g 04). It's written in the docs that you need at lest 3 M's to show a text. But it's not working.

Comment: Nope, I can't reproduce this either - that code returns "05/Apr/2016" for me. Please show a [mcve] - you may want to explicitly specify the locale, to reduce variation between machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MMM/yyyy" ).withLocale( Locale.US ).print( DateTime.now() )
```

Now I'm getting `05/Apr/2016`

Comment: Can you please tell us your default locale? Then the reason for your problem probably becomes clear.

Comment: Both `getResources().getConfiguration().locale` and `Locale.getDefault()` return: **cachedToStringResult: md_US** , **countryCode: US** , **languageCode: md**

Comment: And that is the problem: "md" is not any valid ISO-639-language code. Just look at Google for ISO-639-code-tables. Therefore the JDK (every version) does not know how to handle it and **has no text resources referring to this md-language**. The fact of country US does not matter here because text resource look-up starts with the language and use the country only as secondary information. But if you use `Locale.US` then that is a different locale because its language is English (=en_US).